# Alter BodyContent in doInitBody() method

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee, tags, taglib

I've been following the [jsp tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaow.html) to create my custom tag that generates a body and then evaluates it.

As the docs state:

> setBodyContent: Creates body content and adds to the tag handler
>
> doInitBody: Called before evaluation of the tag body
>
> doAfterBody: Called after evaluation of the tag body

A typical invocation sequence is as follows:

```
t.doStartTag();
out = pageContext.pushBody();
t.setBodyContent(out);
// perform any initialization needed after body content is set
t.doInitBody();
t.doAfterBody();
// while doAfterBody
 returns EVAL_BODY_AGAIN
 we
 // iterate body evaluation
...
t.doAfterBody();
t.doEndTag();
out = pageContext.popBody();
t.release();
```

So I have made by custom tag implementation, that extends **BodyTagSupport**, and in the **doInitBody()** I do:

```
@Override
    public void doInitBody() throws JspException {
        BodyContent content = getBodyContent();
        try {
            content.clearBody();
            content.write("Hello World!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new JspException(e);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and the tag doesn't output a thing..

The taglib definition is easy as:

```
<tag>
        <description>bla bla bla</description>
        <name>test</name>
        <tag-class>mypackage.TestTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>tagdependent</body-content>
        <dynamic-attributes>true</dynamic-attributes>        
    </tag>
```

And the tag is used as:

```
<input:test>content</input:test>
```

But it doesn't output anything.. Any advice on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Also tested by placing getBodyContent().writeOut(pageContext.getOut()) but the outputted body was not evaluated.